# Select only hovered elements instead of all matching elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My HTML is of the form:

```
<ul>
    <li class="tile">
        <span class="hidden"></span>
        <span class="hidden"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">
        <span class="hidden"></span>
        <span class="hidden"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And when an `li` with class `tile` is hovered on I need the first `span` with class `hidden` to have that class removed. When the mouse is moved away that span needs to be hidden again. So far I have this:

```
$(".tile").hover(function () {
    $(this + ":first-child").removeClass("hidden");
}, function () {
    $(this + ":first-child").addClass("hidden");
});
```

However this makes ALL of the `li` with class `tile` do the action, not just the one hovered upon. And the second function gives the `hidden` class to the style sheet reference in the header!

What am I doing wrong? I thought I used `this` correctly.

Comment: I would suggest you look at this plugin -> http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to concatenate `this` with other selectors, as it doesn't do what you think it does.

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) instead:

```
$(".tile").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(":first-child").removeClass("hidden");
}, function () {
    $(this).find(":first-child").addClass("hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hover function should be:

```
$(".tile").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("span").first().removeClass("hidden");
}, function () {
    $(this).find("span").first().addClass("hidden");
});
```